# Solve IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider for EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using DbContextOptionsBuilder for my test ( from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore)

```
 var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<context>();
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(dbname);
```

In one of my tests, I want to test the update

```
 _repository = new CategoryRepository(_userDBContext)
 await _repository.UpdateCategoryAsync(category);
```

The `UpdateCategoryAsync` is using `FirstOrDefaultAsync` and on that project I am using System.Data.Entity.
As a result, I will receive the error :  `The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAs...`

How could I solve this while still using the same packages ( Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore for my test project and EF for where the Update implementation is )?

Comment: So you have old and busted EF in production, and you are trying to use EFCore to take advantage of the UseInMemoryDatabase over your existing models?

Comment: @TheGeneral, exactly, that's the case .(EF 6.4.4 )

Comment: You can't use queryable extension methods of one library with queryable implementations from another library. Both libraries have extension methods with one and the same names, but they work only with "their" objects/interfaces. Shorty, what are you asking not gonna work. And mixing two EFs is a terrible idea anyway as they have so many differences. And InMemoryProvider is not recommended even for EF Core since it is quite different from real database providers.